# `model` must be a `LightningModule` or `torch._dynamo.OptimizedModule`, got `TemporalFusionTransformer`

Tags: time-series, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-forecasting

im trying to temporal fusion transformer from pytorch_forecasting module but im getting the error in trainer.fit method:`model` must be a `LightningModule` or `torch._dynamo.OptimizedModule`, got `TemporalFusionTransformer`.I'm just replicating this paper from 'towardsdatascience'.reference:[https://towardsdatascience.com/temporal-fusion-transformer-time-series-forecasting-with-deep-learning-complete-tutorial-d32c1e51cd91#:~:text=T%20emporal%20F%20usion%20T,dynamics%20of%20multiple%20time%20sequences](https://towardsdatascience.com/temporal-fusion-transformer-time-series-forecasting-with-deep-learning-complete-tutorial-d32c1e51cd91#:%7E:text=T%20emporal%20F%20usion%20T,dynamics%20of%20multiple%20time%20sequences).

Answer (score 6):

There has been an update to `pytorch-forecasting` requirements and pytorch lightning no longer imports as `lightning.pytorch`, but `pytorch_lightning`.

Changing this in `pytorch-forecasting` `basemodel.py` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Soffies' answer is basically correct. The fundamental reason is that import/from lightning.pytorch is incompatible with import/from pytorch_lightning.
In pytorch_forecasting, the author uses import lightning.pytorch extensively.
Therefore, all you need to do is to replace 'pytorch_lightning' with 'lightning.pytorch' in the your code.
Additionally, I encountered this issue after updating to torch2

Comment: would you recommend to change to lightning.pytorch or pytorch_lightening in the long run? Is any preferred?

Answer (score 0):

replace your imports

```
from lightning.pytorch import Trainer #❌
```

```
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer #✅
```